# C - seg fault - cant find error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program (in C) to implement a self referential linked list.  I have written a bit of code and got it to compile but now I'm getting segmentation fault and I have no idea why.  Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1 
#define FALSE 0 
struct Node {  
  int value ; 
  struct Node *next;  
};


void insert(int x, struct Node **pL);
void printList(struct Node *L);

typedef int BOOLEAN;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    struct Node *L;
    for(i = 3 ; i < 20; i+= 2) 
    insert(i,(&L));
    printList(L);
    return 0;
}



void insert(int x, struct Node **pL) {
    if((*pL) == NULL)
    {
        (*pL) = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        (*pL)->value = x;
        (*pL)->next = NULL;
    } else {
        insert(x, &((*pL)->next));
    }
}

void printList(struct Node *L) {
    printf("%d\n", (L)->value);
    if(((L)->next) != NULL) {
        printList((L)->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `struct Node *L = NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `L` and then you use it in `insert` via `*pL`. Try:

```
struct Node *L = NULL;
```

Comment: +1 @Ted As a rule to be forever followed, *NEVER* declare an open-code pointer without initializing it to *something*, be it the result of a function call, an address taken from &somevar, NULL, *anything* but naked indeterminate value-state.